# Using a while-loop to find the maximum integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, max

My assignment is to edit the following code to use a while-loop instead of a for loop to find the maximum in an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = {23, 101, 8, 25, 77, 5};
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > max) {
            max = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}
```

So far, this is what I've been trying to do and have not come up with the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = {23,101,8,25,77,5};
    int i = 0;
    int max = numbers[0];
    while(i<=numbers.length) {
        i=i+1;;
        if (numbers[i] > max) {
            max = numbers[i];
        }
    }
```

If anyone could provide me with some insight as to what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it. I have little experience with while-loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `while` condition slightly and move the `i` increment to after the actual loop body:

```
while(i < numbers.length) {
    if (numbers[i] > max) {
        max = numbers[i];
    }
    i = i + 1; // or simply i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<=` in your `while` loop condition and move incrementing `i` to end of the loop.

```
while (i < numbers.length) {
        if (numbers[i] > max) {
            max = numbers[i];
        }
        i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The while loop is correct. Remove the double semicolon as that is a syntax error and use (sizeof(numbers.length)/sizeof(int)); line to obtain list length.

Comment: You may replace `;;` by `;`, but it is not a syntax error.
In Java there is no `sizeof`, hence it would give a compile error.